# How do you balance Auto Layout with creating frames?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, cgrect

When I'm creating a frame in iOS with `CGRectMake()`, be it setting the `frame` property or using `initWithFrame:`, it asks for the x, y, width and height. I supply these.

But with Auto Layout, I'm next going to say something like: "position its x in the very middle" and "set the width to half the screen", right after I set those with `CGRectMake()` likely differently.

What do I set them as in `CGRectMake()`? 0? An arbitrary value? Something close to what I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using auto-layout, you shouldn't set the `frame` property at all. You can set the `frame`, but there's no purpose in doing so, and only makes your code misleading as the `frame` will be superseded by the dimensions it calculates from the constraints. I would suggest completely defining the dimensions of the controls using constraints and avoid setting the `frame` entirely to avoid confusion.

So, if you're creating views programmatically, instead of `initWithFrame`, just do `init`. Also, do not forget to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`, and add all of the appropriate constraints such that the layout is unambiguous, but with no conflicting constraints, either.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Question: do you prefer setting constraints in code or in storyboard?

Comment: @DougSmith I personally think it's much easier to do it in the storyboard, as it gets you out of the weeds of creating all of the various constraints. But if your control is one that you have to add programmatically, then you have to create the constraints programmatically, too. Using [visual format language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/constraintFundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH2-SW2) often makes creating constraints programmatically easier. But if you can do it in Interface Builder, it's even easier.