# Subclass UIView with UIImageView inside not responding to auto-layout

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to create a `UIView` which has a `UIImage` property that sets 2 `UIImageView`. The effect I'm trying to create is a profile view and is working in storyboard:

[image: Profile View]

However in my app is that it does not respond to auto-layout. The moment it is instantiated in a menu the view overflows the Menu View Controller:

[image]

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class ProfileImageView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable
    var profileImage : UIImage = UIImage()

    @IBInspectable
    var topImageScalePercentage : CGFloat = 50

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        updateLayout()
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        updateLayout()
    }

    func updateLayout() {

        // Create the large background Image View
        let blurredProfileView = UIImageView(frame: self.bounds)
        blurredProfileView.image = profileImage
        blurredProfileView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        blurredProfileView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        // Blur the background Image View
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurView.frame = blurredProfileView.bounds
        blurredProfileView.addSubview(blurView)

        // Add the Blurred Profile View to view
        self.addSubview(blurredProfileView)

        // Create smaller Profile Picture
        var profileRect : CGRect!
        if blurredProfileView.bounds.width < blurredProfileView.bounds.height {
            let width = blurredProfileView.bounds.width * topImageScalePercentage / 100.0
            let height = width // 1:1
            profileRect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: width, height: height)
        } else {
            let height = blurredProfileView.bounds.height * topImageScalePercentage / 100.0
            let width = height // 1:1
            profileRect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: width, height: height)
        }
        let profileImageView = UIImageView(frame: profileRect)
        profileImageView.image = profileImage
        profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.bounds.width / 2
        profileImageView.center = blurredProfileView.center

        self.addSubview(profileImageView)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing auto-layout and frame-based layouts and expecting the frames to automatically update when your views move or resize. That does not happen.

Try constraining the views into place like:

```
func updateLayout() {

    // Create the large background Image View
    let blurredProfileView = UIImageView(image: profileImage)
    blurredProfileView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    blurredProfileView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    self.addSubview(blurredProfileView)
    blurredProfileView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    blurredProfileView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    blurredProfileView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    blurredProfileView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    blurredProfileView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


    // Blur the background Image View
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
    let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

    blurredProfileView.addSubview(blurView)
    blurView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurredProfileView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    blurView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurredProfileView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    blurView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurredProfileView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    blurView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurredProfileView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    blurView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false



    // Create smaller Profile Picture
    var profileRect : CGRect!
    if blurredProfileView.bounds.width < blurredProfileView.bounds.height {
        let width = blurredProfileView.bounds.width * topImageScalePercentage / 100.0
        let height = width // 1:1
        profileRect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: width, height: height)
    }
    else {
        let height = blurredProfileView.bounds.height * topImageScalePercentage / 100.0
        let width = height // 1:1
        profileRect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: width, height: height)
    }

    let profileImageView = UIImageView(image: profileImage)
    profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileRect.width / 2

    self.addSubview(profileImageView)
    profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurredProfileView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurredProfileView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: profileRect.width).isActive = true
    profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: profileRect.height).isActive = true
    profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}
```

Comment: Note: The above code does NOT check whether or not the subviews were already added. If `updateLayout` is called multiple times, you MIGHT have multiple "blurredProfileView" and other views that were added within the function.

Comment: I tried your code and in Storyboard as well as on the test device I get this as a result: http://imgur.com/a/Qz9ne . The blur as well as the smaller profile seem to disappear. The custom UIView is fully constrained and your code seems to add the constraints for the profileViews but it is not responding to it.

Comment: I tried adding a heightAnchor since my storyBoard has a height anchor (4 edges and a height) : blurredProfileView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor) but that has no effect :(

Comment: @Emptyless; Use the View debugger to debug the view hierarchy and see what's happening. I can't see anything wrong with the constraints. I do see that both profileImageView and blurredProfileView use the same UIImage. Also, you can try constraining `profileImageView` to self instead of `blurredProfileView`.

Comment: It has added 0 constraints - so that is what is going wrong. Thanks for this tip! Are you supposed to use the view.addConstraints function because when I use the inspector it says that leftAnchor is a get-only property?

Comment: @Emptyless; I see. I forgot to set the constraints `isActive = true`. Fixed.

Comment: it works now, thanks! The new Swift 3 syntax has me change it to 'isActive' as a heads up :-)

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003363/how-do-you-balance-auto-layout-with-creating-frames), you should not manipulate frames if you plan to use autolayout

Comment: But I don't set the frame explicitly. I use the self.bounds (local coordinates)  to create a frame for the subView of UIView. That frame should update when the autolayout-constraints change the bounds of UIView. Basically making it so that the SubView always has the same size/frame as the UIView - I have the view in a Storyboard

Comment: Yes but the accepted answer of the post I linked explicitly states that you should use -init instead of -initWithFrame:. did you try to get rid of all those CGRect to see if it's better

Comment: I used @Brandon's answer above to fix it :-) , thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the frames/layers of your subviews/layers you can only do this after autolayout has completed its frame calculations ie override [layoutSubViews](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) and move your frame code their.  Alternatively use auto layout.  Since you just want to fill your superview you can use the following extension:

```
    extension UIView {
        func constrainToSuperView() {
            translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            let attributes: [NSLayoutAttribute] = [.centerX, .centerY, .width, .height]
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(attributes.map{NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: $0, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.superview, attribute: $0, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)})
        }
    }
```